# Getting started with a Freescale Micro

Tags: programmer

I have been using PICs for years and am used to having a programmer like the PICKIT to program the chip with. I have a project now for which I think a Freescale micro might be a better choice. I have found there is a free version of Code Warrior, but I am not exactly sure how the programming of the chip works. What is the process of doing this?

Comment: @Mark I have removed your link. Are you using a proxy server? It would help to say what micro you are looking at.

Comment: Mark was last here on the day this question was asked, and the provided link was through a proxy server.  Therefore, we probably will never know which micro is being referenced.  Given the existing answers, it seems sensible and useful to assume an [HCS08](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/HCS08RMV1.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that Freescale would be better than Microchip these days, last time I tried something from Freescale it was just a pain, at that time they had no hobbyist support and the stuff was way harder to use.... But it was some time ago, so maybe they have changed, but I'm curious to why you think thy are better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what device it is, but if it's a 68HC08 you need a USB MON08 Multilink:

"The MON08 Multilink is an easy-to-use, low-cost development tool for Freescale's 68HC08 Flash MCUs. The MON08 Multilink provides in-circuit emulation, debugging and programming through the 68HC08's standard MON08 serial debug/breakpoint interface."

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=USBMULTILINK08&tab=Buy_Parametric_Tab&fromSearch=false

It's equivalent to a PICkit, but more expensive at $99.

Comment: Opinion only, of course:  I'm surprised at the rate that people down vote queries that can be much improved by having some more information added. As it's 10 hours since the question has been asked and the question is already about half way to being closed, worst case a person could post a question and come back a day later and find it closed. More specific information would, of course, help, but so would giving the question asker a chance to provide it.

Comment: Note that this is no longer manufactured. We used a [USB Multilink Universal](http://www.pemicro.com/products/product_viewDetails.cfm?product_id=15320137) from PEmicro. Not cheap at USD 120, though.

Comment: It is available: http://uk.farnell.com/freescale-semiconductor/usbmultilink08e/kit-icd-programmer-cable-hc08/dp/1579898?Ntt=USBMULTILINK08E. The non-RoHS version has been discontinued.

Comment: @Russell: Playing "20 questions" is annoying, time consuming, and doesn't make the point well to the OP and everyone else listening in.  A poorly worded question is just that, and should be dealt with expeditiously.  The OP can start a new question, this time hopefully asking it better.  But this way he's (and everyone else) is on notice that vague or confusing questions are not tolerated.

Comment: @Russell: I ref youth soccer in my spare time on weekends in the spring and fall.  The coaches can tell a kid 20 times what a good throw in is, but they still frequently get it wrong at the under 10 level.  At that age we give them some slack with a explanation and a do-over, but it still happens a lot.  At the under 12 level we give the ball to the other team.  It's amazing how fast they suddenly learn how to do a proper throw in.  I think this principal is well applied to good and bad questions too.

Comment: @Olin all about the toe drag...

Comment: @Russell McMahon I am confused as to what you are trying to say. Are you unhappy with Leon's answer or with people down voting? It sounds like you are unhappy with the down votes which means this comment should have been on the question instead of the answer.

Comment: @RusselMcMahon, down-voting does not close, no one has voted for that(and it takes 5 or a mod). The common trait among poor questions is no continuation of returning. If they take the time to ask a well worded question they find simple questions are often resolved by taking a moment to look into getting details. Asking quickly and wanting someone to just fix it is tempting or give you the perfect link, but it involves lots of guessing on our part. They are not going to get rep(a rough measure of their site and electronics knowledge) for that. They need to ask detailed thought provoking of that

Comment: @RusselMcMahon, why not put this comment on the question? This doe snot pertain to the answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's far, FAR better to focus on upvoting good questions, than worrying about downvoting or closing "bad" questions.  Only the most egregiously off-topic or spam questions really need to be downvoted to flagged for closure.   Bad questions will naturally just fall off the radar as good questions are upvoted anyway.

Comment: @OlinLathrop closing an incomplete question with the idea the the poster "can start a new question, this time hopefully asking it better" would be in conflict with the policy against duplicate questions.

Comment: Sorry to jump on the dogpile but I agree about vague questions. I see lots of stuff with no constraints or budget and a vague description of the problem. For a site with a hobbyist/DIY/hacker bent it would be nice to make it clear where you are between etching PCBs at home and installing software on a PC just to make something work. "A Freescale micro" almost makes me suspect trolling, can't you look at their website and pick a family or have an informed question about choosing a family? If you "think" a Freescale micro would be better you must have a reason so work it into the question!

Answer (score 0):

I got into Freescale HCS08's by using their CodeWarrior software and a DEMO9S08LL16 demo kit. It was all pretty easy to get going and I rather like the HCS08LL16. It's a decent low-power chip with lots of fairly easy to use peripherals.